# Search items in a list, what is good to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

It is not really a issue, im just wondering I have a list with alot of names and a search function bounded to it. It is all done in jquery and just put every element on display none when it is not matched with the input

It works perfect but I am not really sure this is the 'cleanest' way to do this, cause every element gets updated with a bunch of css styles everytime.

Is it worth to try out angular or some similar solution to achieve it or a complete overkill for such a small task?

Updated:!

My current code:

```
    var value = $input.val(),
        $persons = $teamCatagory.find('li');

    $persons.hide();

    var found = $persons
        .filter(function () {
            $persons.hide();
            return $(this).text()
                .match(new RegExp(value, "gi"))
        })
        .show()
        .length > 0;

    if(value.length === 0 ) {
        $persons.show().removeAttr('style');
    }

    if (!found) {
        $persons.hide();
        console.log("found nothing");
    }
};
```

Comment: try jquery's autocomplete

Comment: If you're already using only jQuery, don't mix Angular into it just for this one task. Post your code, maybe we can help clean it out ;-)

Comment: there you go @TomekBuszewski

Comment: You can improved your code a little: http://jsfiddle.net/a9k9sLdx/ But with Angular it will be pretty much the same anyway (showing and hiding with style.display, I mean).

Comment: Aah thanks!, I thought angular just add and remove blocks of HTML instead of just simple hiding them wiht css properties. (not sure, didn't really looked into it)

Comment: Using Angular only for this task seems overkill indeed.

Comment: What about jquery grep:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/. I think the search in grep is more efficient on list and arrays...